# Prove R/I is commutative

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let R be a commutative ring and I an ideal in R. Prove R/I is commutative.

So to start off, would I use the fact that rs-sr is in I ?

Comment: I'm stuck where to start I'm wondering if rs- sr in I is a good start ?

Comment: what is the form of elements in $\frac{R}{I}$? how are they multiplied?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking I know I have an abelian group because all rings are abelian groups. This is what I have. Assume R/I is commutative for some commutative ring R and ideal I.  Thus, ab+I=ba+I. R/I is an abelian group thus ab+I- (ba+I) = 0 +I which implies ab-ba is in I. Does that prove commutativity tho?

Comment: or why wouldn't it be enough to just say R/I is a ring and thus all rings are abelian groups which implies it is commutative.

Comment: The "abelian" only applies to the group operation (usually referred to as addition). A commutative ring must have commutative multiplication.

Comment: ahhh thanks so much that clarifies a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $I$ an ideal of $R$. The elements of $R/I$ are cosets $I + a$ where $a \in R$ and the addition is defined as $I + a + I + b = I + (a+b)$ while the multiplications is defined as $(I + a)(I + b) = I + ab$. You're trying to prove that $R/I$ is a commutative ring, i.e, $(I + a)(I + b) = I + (ab) = I + (ba) = (I + b)(I + a)$. Recall that $I + (ab) = I + (ba) \iff ab - ba \in I$. We know that $R$ is commutative, so we have $ab - ba = ab - ab = 0$ which is clearly in $I$ since it is an ideal, thus $R/I$ is a commutative ring.

Remember that we are trying to prove that the multiplication is commutative, so the fact that all rings are abelian groups with respect to addition does not imply that it is a commutative ring.

Comment: thanks this proof was really helpful!

Comment: how do we get ab-ba=ab-ab=0 ?

Comment: is it ab-ba=ab-ab....-ba=-ab.....-ba=-ba...(commutative)....1=1... 0=0 ?

Comment: Since $R$ is commutative, for all $a, b \in R$, we have $ab = ba$. This means that $I + (ab) = I + (ba)$ since $ab - ba = ab = ab = 0 \in I$ since $I$ is an ideal of $R$.

Answer (score 1):

$(a+I)(b+I)=(ab)+I=(ba)+I=(b+I)(a+I){}{}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 0):

**If *R* is not commutative and we want to show *R/I* is commutative if and only if *(rs-sr) $\epsilon$ I*:**

*R/I* is the quotient ring and the elements are all the cosets engendered by *I* partitioning *R*. Thus, *R/I* = {*r+I* : *r $\epsilon$ R*} since all the cosets are of the form *r+I*. To show that a ring is commutative, it must hold that for any *r,s* in the ring, *rs*=*sr*.

In the quotient ring, multiplication is defined as, *(r+I)(s+I) = rs+I*. Consider the elements *r+I* and *s+I*. Now, to prove the assertion: $$(r+I)(s+I)=(s+I)(r+I)$$
$$rs+I=sr+I$$
$$rs+I-sr=I$$
$$rs-sr=I-I$$
Since I is a ring, *I - I* is simply *I* because of closure under addition. Thus, *R/I* is commutative only if, for *r,s $\epsilon$ R*, *(rs-sr) $\epsilon$ R*.

**If *R* is commutative, and we want to show *R/I* is commutative:**

See Jorge's solution, where the main step is the *ab = ba* for *a,b $\epsilon$ R* since *R* is commutative.